# How to go from codepen to running locally on pc

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, angular-material

I would like to run the following codepen on my PC?

```
http://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV
```

I have nodejs installed, and have exported the codepen as a zip, extracted in -

but how do i actually run it?

I have tried `'http-server ./d' ?` and `'npm run serve'`. Sorry this is a newb question, but I can't find documentation on web for it, or in angularmaterialwebsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install http-server package [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) using following command

```
$ npm install http-server -g
```

then on you run a http-server pointing to your extracted folder using following command

```
$ http-server path/to/your/extracted/folder -p 8989
```